# PHPBB External Login partially working

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, external, phpbb

So I have been working a an external PHPBB login script, at present it works to the stage

1. User logs in to external site with their external username and password
2. Function runs in background which checks whether they are registered on the forum, if they are not they are registered (This works fine)
3. The user is directed to an external dashboard which presents them with their forum username and any inbox messages they may have (This works fine)
4. User clicks through to forum and even though they are supposed to be automatically logged in, they are asked to login again? (This is the part which is not working)

So basically, the forum shouldn't be asking the user to re-authenticate once they have externally logged in, has anyone else experience this issue? I have set the $auth->login to autologin but for some reason it is not taking effect

**Here is how the login is handled**

```
                $user->session_begin();
                $auth->acl($user->data);
                $user->setup();


                    if($user->data['is_registered'])
                    {
                        //User is already logged in
                        ?>
                            <p>Welcome back, <?php echo $user->data['username']; ?>, You currently have <?php echo $user->data['user_unread_privmsg']; ?> new messages</p>
                        <?php
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $result = $auth->login($username, $password, true);

                       ?>
                            <p>Welcome, <?php echo $user->data['username']; ?>, You currently have  <?php echo $user->data['user_unread_privmsg']; ?> new messages</p>



                        <?php
                    }
```

Comment: Implementing an external login for phpBB3 isn't easy and is discouraged by most phpBB developers. If you would like us to help you, please be more specific about how you manage to log users in with your external authentication script so we could track what is happening.

Comment: try changing `if($user->data['is_registered'])` to `if ($user->data['user_id'] == ANONYMOUS)` this will check if the user is logged into phpBB